# Why SASS code is not showed up in colored form in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, sass, visual-studio-setup-proje

[image: SASS CODE in BLACK AND WHITE!]

I am using Visual Studio Code for the front end development project. Unfortunately, VS Code stopped showing me colored version of **SASS** file. May I ask please what is the solution?

Comment: See "Plain text" in the bottom right of your screen ? Click on it to select sass and you'll get the syntax higlighting.
sass files are probably not associated with scss syntax, that might be the reason.

Comment: @AmauryHanser, thank you for your help. You solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem, you can install this extension in vscode:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Syler.sass-indented